# While assigning a big json to clob in Oracle pl/sql getting error String literal too long

Tags: json, oracle, plsql

While assigning the big json to clob I am getting the above error.

Assignment code is as follows:

```
  declare
    l_response clob;
   begin
    dbms_lob.createtemporary(l_response, TRUE);
    l_response:= Very big json;
    dbms_output.put_line ('Inside');
   end ;
```

I think clob can take huge data.But why in this case it is not able to assign.

Comment: In Oracle a string literal cannot exceed 4000 bytes (or 32000 if you turned extended strings on). There is no way around that limit.

Comment: The how can I assign a big json to a clob? Any way around.Requirement is to assign that to a clob ,then process that to get the tag value to insert into oracle table

Comment: Split your json text into multiple text ( less than 4000 chars each ) and append them to the clob variable.

Comment: How do I do that.Can you please give me some example.If JSON comes dynamically how to break into smaller pieces and append them to update?